# How is `asl_set_filter` actually used?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, logging, syslog

I am trying in vain to put `asl_set_filter` to use. I am aware the default filter prevents `ASL_LEVEL_INFO` and `ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG` from logging to `syslogd`. Using `asl_set_filter` as I am below should remove that limitation:

```
    aslclient _logClient = asl_open("LoggerPlayCmd", "com.apple.console", ASL_OPT_STDERR);
    asl_set_filter(_logClient, ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG));

    #define LOG(level) asl_log(_logClient, NULL, (level), "Logging entry at level %s(%d)", (#level), (level));
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_EMERG);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_ALERT);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_CRIT);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_ERR);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_WARNING);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_INFO);
    LOG(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG);

    asl_close(_logClient);
```

However the output visibly in Console.app is excludes the INFO and DEBUG lines, as though the call to asl_set_limit was not made.

```
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_EMERG(0)
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_ALERT(1)
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_CRIT(2)
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_ERR(3)
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_WARNING(4)
 14/03/2016 10:13:46.407 LoggerPlayCmd[29684]: Log entry ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE(5)
```

Whatever am I doing wrong?

M.

Comment: [This](http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2009-09/msg01136.html) is old, but perhaps it still applies?